# Find PDF by calculating CDF

Tags: probability

Let X be a continous random variable with PDF

$$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2} \; \forall x\in \mathbb{R} $$
and let $Y = \sqrt{|X|}$. Find $f_Y(y)$

I am supposed to find the CDF of Y and from that find the PDF of Y.

We observe that $R_Y=[0,\infty)$

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y)=P\left(\sqrt{|X|}\le y\right)=P(-y^2\le X\le y^2)=$$
$$=P(X\le y^2)-P(X\le -y^2)= f_X(y^2)-f_X(-y^2).$$

Now it is possible to find the PDF of the CDF: 
$$f_Y(y) = F_Y'(y)=f_X(y^2)\cdot 2y+f_X(-y^2)\cdot 2y = \frac{2y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-y^4}{2}+\frac{2y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{y^4}{2}.$$

I am not sure if this is the correct PDF or if I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is one mistake at the end: $f_X(-y^2)$ is not $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{y^4}2}$, but
$$f_X(-y^2)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^4}2},$$
since $-(-y^2)^2=-(-1)^2(y^2)^2=-y^4$.

So you can add the two terms, which are equal, and get
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{4y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-y^4}{2}=2y{\sqrt{\frac2\pi}}e^\frac{-y^4}{2}.$$

Of course, this is valid for $y>0$. It is easy to see that $F_Y(y)=0$ for $y\le0$, and so you have $F_Y'(y)=0$ for $y<0$.

Answer (score 0):

I note a typo in your derivation (corrected by replacing $f_X$ by $F_X$):

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y)=P(\sqrt|x|\le y)=P(-y^2\le x\le y^2)=P(x\le y^2)-P(x\le -y^2) = F_X(y^2)-F_X(-y^2)$$

Completing this:

$$F_Y(y) = \Phi(y^2)-\Phi(-y^2)=\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Finally:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{d \,F_Y(y)}{dy}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,e^{-y^4/2}\frac{2y}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{8}{\pi}}y\,e^{-y^4/2}$$